# Reprojection of nc file with gdal.Warp gives a NoneType object

Tags: python, gdalwarp

In the following code I try to make a file which should have the same grid and bounds as the mask.

```
mask=gdal.Open(path1,gdal.GA_ReadOnly)
print(mask.GetGeoTransform())
src=gdal.Open(path2,gdal.GA_ReadOnly)
dst=gdal.GetDriverByName('NetCDF').Create(pathdst,xsize=mask.RasterXSize,ysize=mask.RasterYSize)
dst.SetGeoTransform(mask.GetGeoTransform())
print (dst.GetGeoTransform())
dst.SetProjection(mask.GetProjection())
bnds=(mask.GetGeoTransform()[0],mask.GetGeoTransform()[3]-mask.RasterYSize,mask.GetGeoTransform()[0]+mask.RasterXSize,mask.GetGeoTransform()[3])
optt=gdal.WarpOptions(format='NetCDF',xRes=mask.RasterXSize,yRes=mask.RasterYSize,outputBounds=bnds,width=mask.GetGeoTransform()[1],dstSRS=mask.GetProjection())
dst=gdal.Warp(dst,src,options=optt)
dst=None
src=None
mask=None
```

but it throws an error

> TypeError: in method 'wrapper_GDALWarpDestDS', argument 4 of type >'GDALWarpAppOptions *'`

Code

```
mask=gdal.Open(path1,gdal.GA_ReadOnly)
src=gdal.Open(path2,gdal.GA_ReadOnly)
bnds=(mask.GetGeoTransform()[0],mask.GetGeoTransform()[3]-mask.RasterYSize,mask.GetGeoTransform()[0]+mask.RasterXSize,mask.GetGeoTransform()[3])
optt=gdal.WarpOptions(format='netCDF',xRes=mask.RasterXSize,yRes=mask.RasterYSize,outputBounds=bnds,width=mask.GetGeoTransform()[1])
dst=gdal.Warp(pathdst,src,options=optt)
print(dst.RasterCount)
dst=None
src=None
mask=None
```

generates dst=NoneType and no file.

The code

```
dst=gdal.GetDriverByName('netCDF').Create(ppath+'test1.nc',mask.RasterXSize,mask.RasterYSize,1,gdalconst.GDT_Float32)
dst.SetGeoTransform(mask.GetGeoTransform())
dst.SetProjection(mask.GetProjection())
ds=gdal.ReprojectImage(src_prec, dst, prec_info[0],mask_info[0], gdalconst.GRA_Bilinear) 
del ds,dst
```

works properly, but I can't do the same thing for multiband raster.

How can I reproject multiband src to mask domain with GDAL?

Today I tried to do the same thing in QGIS and python with same files. I took 1 band from src and saved it as nc. In QGis it worked perfectly:

```
gdalwarp -ot Float32 -t_srs EPSG:4326 -r bilinear -of GTiff -tr 1 1 -te 19.5 " 40.0" " 70.5" " 75.0" -co COMPRESS=DEFLATE -co PREDICTOR=1 -co ZLEVEL=6 -wo OPTIMIZE_SIZE=TRUE dst.nc
```

I copied all parameters to python and got NoneType result.

```
mask=gdal.Open(path1,gdal.GA_ReadOnly)#.GetRasterBand(1)
print(mask.RasterCount)
src=gdal.Open(os.getcwd()+'/test1/mask.nc',gdal.GA_ReadOnly)
bnds=(mask.GetGeoTransform()[0],mask.GetGeoTransform()[3]-mask.RasterYSize,mask.GetGeoTransform()[0]+mask.RasterXSize,mask.GetGeoTransform()[3])
optt=gdal.WarpOptions(format='netCDF',resampleAlg='bilinear',warpOptions=('OPTIMIZE_SIZE=TRUE'),creationOptions=('COMPRESS=DEFLATE','PREDICTOR=1','ZLEVEL=6'),outputType=gdalconst.GDT_Float32,srcSRS='EPSG:4326',dstSRS='EPSG:4326',xRes=mask.RasterXSize,yRes=mask.RasterYSize,outputBounds=bnds,width=mask.GetGeoTransform()[1])
dst=gdal.Warp(pathdst,src,options=optt)
```

gdal version -- 3.0.4